# Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}{n^2}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let's $x_n\ge0$ and $$\overline{\lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n}\lt+\infty,~~\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_n}{n}=0.$$Prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}{n^2}=0.$$
I have no idea how I can start the proof.

Thanks!

Comment: I would start with the definition of limit: for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an integer $N$ such that for all $n > N$ we have $\left| \frac{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}{n^2} - 0 \right| < \epsilon$

Comment: I tried to use your hint, but I can't complete the proof. Could you give me some more hints?

Comment: Perhaps you can try something like , $x_n=\log n$. I feel the problem is $\sum x_n<Kn =K\sum_n 1$, and the tail term of the series tend to 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first requirement implies that there is some $R\in\left(0,\infty\right)$
such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_{i}}{n}\leq R
$$
holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Now, let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Your second requirement shows that there is some $n_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{x_{n}}{n}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2R}$ holds for all $n\geq n_{1}$.

> Let $S:=\max_{i=1,\dots,n_{1}}x_{i}$ and choose $n_{2}\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n_{2}\geq n_{1}$ and $\frac{SR}{n_{2}}\leq\varepsilon/2$.

We now derive for $n>n_{2}\geq n_{1}$ that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_{i}^{2}}{n^{2}} & = & \left[\max_{i=1,\dots,n_{1}}x_{i}\right]\cdot\frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n_{1}}\frac{x_{i}}{n}+\left[\max_{j=n_{1}+1,\dots,n}\frac{x_{j}}{n}\right]\cdot\sum_{i=n_{1}+1}^{n}\frac{x_{i}}{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}

I believe you can take it from there. Otherwise:

> \begin{eqnarray*}\dots \\ & \leq & \frac{SR}{n}+\left[\max_{j=n_{1}+1,\dots,n}\frac{x_{j}}{j}\right]\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_{i}}{n}\\ & \leq & \frac{SR}{n}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2R}\cdot R\leq\varepsilon.\end{eqnarray*}

Remark: What we are doing in the above is essentially an interpolation argument between an $\ell^1$ estimate and an $\ell^\infty$ estimate to get an $\ell^2$ estimate . The only problem is that the $\ell^\infty$ estimate only holds in the limit, so that one has to treat the first finitely many terms in a special way.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: use the weighted variant of Cauchy's limit theorem (see page 34 of [Knopp's book](https://books.google.hu/books?id=u4QUAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA18&hl=hu&pg=PA34#v=onepage&q&f=false))

- Set $y_n=x_n+1$, then  $y_n$ has the same properties as $x_n$ in the original question.
- $z_n=\frac{y_1\frac{y_1}{1}+\ldots y_n \frac{y_n}{n}}{y_1+\ldots +y_n} \to 0$  (by Cauchy's theorem)
- $u_n=\frac{\frac{y_1^2+\ldots y_n^2}{n}} {y_1+\ldots +y_n} \le z_n$ (a trivial lower bound for the numerator)
- $\frac{\frac{y_1^2+\ldots y_n^2}{n}} {Kn} < u_n$ (since $y_1+\ldots+y_n<Kn$ for some $K>0$)
- By noting that $y_n^2$ majorizes $x_n^2$ we can deduce the needed result.