# For a positive real sequence $(a_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

For a positive real sequence $(a_n)$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}=L$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {a_n}{n}=0$$

Then show that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots+a_n^2}{n^2}=0$$

I have tried to create an inequality using Cauchy-Schwarz and using the Squeeze Theorem, but it didn't work, and I have thought of using Stolz-Cesàro's Theorem, but it also didn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Note: the second hypothesis is redundant as it follows from the first. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1729872/169852) for a proof.

Comment: I understand that the second hypothesis follows from the first. Thanks!

Comment: You can use Cauchy-Schwartz to show that $\sum (a_i/n)^2 < (1/n\sum |a_i|)^2$

Comment: Hint: For any $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N$ such that $a_k \leq \epsilon k$ for all $k\geq N$. This estimate gives you $$\frac{a_N^2 + \cdots + a_n^2}{n^2} \leq \epsilon\frac{a_N+ \cdots +a_n}{n}$$ for $n\geq N$. Can you use this to conclude the desired claim?

Comment: To Doug M, many of my friends have failed to use Cauchy Schwartz, may I ask for further explanation?

Comment: To Sangchul Lee, I don't understand how to get the estimate inequality,,

Comment: @zxcvber: If $N \leq k \leq n$, then $a_k \leq \epsilon k \leq \epsilon n$, so $a_k^2 / n^2 \leq \epsilon a_k / n$.

Comment: Then if I take the limit n to infinity on both sides, I think the left hand side would be what we want, but what do I do with the right hand side? I get $\epsilon L$, but I'm not sure whether I can conclude it is equal to zero since $\epsilon$ is any real number.

Comment: @zxcvber $$0 \leq \frac{a_N^2 + \cdots + a_n^2}{n^2} \leq \epsilon \frac{a_N + \cdots + a_n}{n} \leq \epsilon \frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n}$$ since all of the $a_k$ are nonnegative. As $n \to \infty$, the right hand side converges to $\epsilon L$. Thus the liminf and limsup of $(a_N^2 + \cdots + a_n^2)/n^2$ are sandwiched between $0$ and $\epsilon L$. Since this is true for any $\epsilon > 0$, in fact the liminf and limsup both equal zero, so its limit exists and equals zero.

Comment: This can be generalized to arbitrary exponents $p > 1$: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4808974/42969

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=0$, for any $\epsilon\gt0$, there is an $N_\epsilon$ so that for $k\ge N_\epsilon$, $\frac{a_k}{k}\le\epsilon$.

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=N_\epsilon}^na_k^2
&=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=N_\epsilon}^n\frac{a_k^2}{k^2}\frac{k^2}{n^2}\\
&\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=N_\epsilon}^n\frac{a_k^2}{k^2}\frac{k}{n}\\
&\le\epsilon\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=N_\epsilon}^n\frac{a_k}{k}\frac{k}{n}\\
&=\epsilon\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=N_\epsilon}^na_k\\[3pt]
&\le\epsilon L\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
For any $N_\epsilon$,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{N_\epsilon}a_k^2=0\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2\le\epsilon L\tag{3}
$$
Since $(3)$ is true for any $\epsilon\gt0$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2=0\tag{4}
$$

Comment: Wow! Fully understood ! Thanks!

Comment: +1, nice proof.Do you happen to know whether the hypothesis that $a_n \geq 0$ is necessary? I'm interested to see a counterexample but have not been able to come up with one.

Comment: I believe that $a_n=(-1)^{n-1}n^{3/4}$ is a counterexample. $$\left|\,\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^na_k\,\right|\sim\frac12n^{-1/4}$$ and $$\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2\sim\frac25n^{1/2}$$

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks, I was trying $(-1)^n \sqrt{n}$ but thought I had convinced myself that $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$$was divergent. But now I'm playing around with it numerically, and it appears to converge to zero, so I must have made an error somewhere. The squares work out OK:$$\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}$$which converges to $1/2$, so $(-1)^n \sqrt{n}$ is also a counterexample.

Comment: @Bungo: Yes. $$\left|\,\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\sqrt{k}\,\right|\sim\frac12n^{-1/2}$$

Comment: @robjohn: Do you happen to know if the condition $a_n/n \to 0$ is necessary? I am asking because a generalized version with exponent $p > 1$ was asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4808974/42969, but without that condition.

Comment: Btw, should this be closed as a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/858134/42969 (or the other way around), or merged with that other thread?

Comment: @MartinR: Suppose that there is an $\epsilon\gt0$ so that for all $N$, there is an $n\ge N$ so that $\left\vert\frac{a_n}n\right\vert\ge\epsilon$; that is, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}n\ne0$. Then, there is an $\epsilon\gt0$ so that for all $N$, there is an $n\ge N$ so that  $\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2}{n^2}\ge\epsilon^2$; that is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2}{n^2}\ne0$. Doesn't the second requirement follow from the first?

Comment: @robjohn: But $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2}{n^2} = 0$ is the desired *conclusion.* What I wonder is if the given condition $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}=L$ already implies $a_n/n \to 0$ or not. – If I can't figure it out then I'll post that as a separate question.

Comment: @MartinR: Yes, that is the desired conclusion, and I was trying to show that if we do not have $\frac{a_n}n\to0$, we do not have $\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2}{n^2}\to0$. My comment about the second requirement following from the first is that $\frac {a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}n\to L$ implies $\frac{a_n}n\to0$.

Comment: @robjohn: Your last sentence is the part which is not clear to me. Does $\frac {a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}n\to L$ imply $\frac{a_n}n\to0$? Perhaps I am overlooking something simple.

Comment: @MartinR: $\underbrace{\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}n}_{L+\epsilon_n}-\underbrace{\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{n-1}}{n-1}}_{L+\epsilon_{n-1}}=\frac{a_n}n-\underbrace{\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{n-1}}{n(n-1)}}_{\frac{L+\epsilon_{n-1}}n}$

Comment: @robjohn: That's it, thank you!

Comment: I should have paid more attention to the comments at the question, where this has already been pointed out :)